# What is the meaning/word of each feature in 20 newsgroups dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, newsgroup

I want to use the 20 newsgroups dataset to test an algorithm, and analysis the significant words for each group.

In the website provided by [University of Toronto](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~larocheh/public/datasets/20newsgroups/20newsgroups_train_binary_5000_voc.txt). But I can't find the correspond vocabulary file for this dataset. So is there anyone else could give me a light?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [here](http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/) for the 20 newsgroups dataset.  It also includes a vocabulary file, but it may not be consistent with the file you have so it might help to use all the files there.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: I know this official website, but the pre-processing of that data may lost some information and the result is also unpleasant. After excluding the Stopwords from the 20news-bydate-matlab.tgz, the remain vocabulary still contains some words like, 'sgi, cec, att...'. And I have no idea of change the words with their stems.